# How to extract information from a binary file knowing the target info

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, decryption, unknown-data

I have some measured data comes from a various types of sensors. The sensors are connected to a data-logger in order to store measurement data. After measurement, the data transported and stored in a logosense data-logger.

**EDIT:** For reading the stored measurement data we can use "HYDRAS 3" a software developed by OTT (using RS232 serial connection and OTT hrdrosence protocol). After reading the data this [read-file](https://privatebin.net/?e57a3210c8ba7673#BKqxHMT8wR4chTygifft9iGdCZADT2fGdhWtHT1N2U4B) has been obtained. At the same time we have monitored the serial port and the communication between the data-logger and HYDRAS to obtain the following [monitor-file](https://privatebin.net/?625ee60b6c8749ec#GRK2MQFZbHbm2Eghqt1pLEeVoRiLCzAef3AW8eQur3PE).

My question is how can i map these two file and extract the measured data at different measurement times from the monitor-file?(or just understand the file).

It seems that my question is not a cryptography problem, I was wondering how Reverse Engineering can solve my problem. Any starting tips?

P.S. the read-file is just for level sensor and the measured data are in meters. e.g. 3.522 at time 10:00, 3.515 at time 11:00 and both are measured on 11/11/2019

Any help or guidelines will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please share the files somewhere accessible and include, in the question, a hexdump of the beginning of the files.

Comment: @IanCook Sorry for the links. I updated them!

Comment: The links expired. Please repost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it is surprising that HYDRAS 3 does not allow you to export data at least in csv format.
2. monitor-file is a log file not so interesting
3. 

### all data you needs are in the read-file
I quickly adapted an html file, which I use to extract my data from a text file, to your read-file.
It draws a curve of your data.
The ERR.05 ERR.10 value are replaced by the value 0.000
If it can help you, here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    
    <head>
        <META content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2" http-equiv="content-type">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" />
        
        <title>extract data from text file</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="header">
                
                <div id="main">
                    
                    <h1>extract data from text file (read-file.txt HYDRAS 3)</h1>
                    <p>Nota: <BR>
                        Adapt to your needs in the function parseFile <BR>
                        <BR>
                    </p>
                    
                    <form name="frmParse" action="">
                        <p>
                            File:
                            <input type="file" name="fileinput" onchange='openFile(event)' />
                        </p>
                        
                        <p>Output:</p>
                        <p>
                            <textarea name="ed_output" rows="10" cols="87" style="width: 700px;"></textarea>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div id="graphdiv2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                </div>
                
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
                    
                    document.frmParse.ed_output.value = "";
                    var mytext=[];
                    var csv_data=[];
                    var csv_firstline="time,value\n";
                    String.prototype.beginsWith = function (string) {
                        return(this.indexOf(string) === 0);
                    };
                    
                    function parseFile() {
                        document.frmParse.ed_output.value = "";
                        
                        var index = 0;
                        var newtext=csv_firstline;
                        var v1="";
                        var v2="";
                        var date="";
                        var newArray = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < mytext.length -1 ; i++ ) {
                            if (mytext[i].includes(" Date:")){ 
                                v1=mytext[i].match(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d/g);
                                date=(moveLastArrayElementToFirstIndex(v1.toString().split("/"))).join('-') ;// date mm/dd/yyyy become yyyy-mm-dd
                            }
                            if (mytext[i].includes(".")){ 
                                v2=mytext[i].match(/ (.*\..*) /g);
                                if (v2!=null){
                                    var time=mytext[i].match(/\((\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\)/g).toString().replace(/[()]/g, '');
                                    var txt=date +"T" +time.toString() +"Z," + v2.toString().trim().replace(/(Err.\d\d)/g, '0.000');//Err. value become 0.000
                                    newtext+=txt +"\n";
                                    newArray.push(txt);
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        document.frmParse.ed_output.value = newtext;
                        csv_data=newArray.join("\n");
                        processData();
                    }
                    
                    //graph csv with Dygraph
                    function processData() {
                        g2 = new Dygraph(
                        document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
                        csv_data,
                        {
                            xlabel: " ",
                            ylabel: " ",
                            title: csv_firstline,
                            showRangeSelector: true,
                            rangeSelectorHeight: 30,
                            rangeSelectorPlotStrokeColor: 'black',
                            rangeSelectorPlotFillColor: 'grey'
                        }
                        );
                    }
                    
                    
                    //Moves last element in an array to the front
                    function moveLastArrayElementToFirstIndex(this_array) {
                        var new_array = new Array();
                        new_array[0] = this_array[this_array.length-1]; //first element is last element    
                        for(var i=1;i<this_array.length;i++) { //subsequent elements start at 1
                            new_array[i] = this_array[i-1];
                        }
                        return new_array;
                    }
                    
                    
                    function readAsText(file) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function() {
                            mytext = reader.result.split("\n");
                            document.frmParse.ed_output.value = "";
                            parseFile();
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                    }
                    
                    
                    var openFile = function(event) {
                        document.frmParse.ed_output.value = "";
                        var input = event.target;
                        readAsText(input.files[0]);
                    };
                    
                    function clearFileInput(){
                        document.frmParse.fileinput.value = "";
                    }
                    
                    
                </script>
                
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: thank you for your time sir. what i am trying to accomplish here is to somewhat simulate HYDRAS, and have my own "HYDRAS", so i think i need to understand the monitor-file as my first step, but dont know how to start. any tips?

Comment: It's clearer now and more ambitious, I've done a little analysis of the monitor-file image file here: https://i.imgur.com/Xv9sR4P.jpg
Oddly, I did not find any documentation on the commands to send type: F0000
Fxxxx of commands followed or not by a parameter
Kxxxxx of the variables returned by the device
K6010 contains the number of bytes of data that will follow
48 bytes = 24 words (1 by hour) can be split

Comment: Thank you! Thats a big help. I'll try this on other sensors and settings and hope to achieve the desired result.